# Truncated incorrect datetime value

Tags: python, mysql, django

I have the following query that running in SQLyog

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

If I run the same query in Python or Django, I get this message:

```
Warning: Truncated incorrect datetime value: '2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00'
```

I've printed out the query from python to ensure it's the same as above. It is identical (including the ending semicolon). I suspect that it's having issues with the timezone offset, but I don't know why it'd work in SQLyog then.

The query that is printed is:

```
--------------------------------------------------
SELECT * FROM sb_bans WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
--------------------------------------------------
```

The Django code used to run this query is:

```
query = """SELECT * FROM sb_bans WHERE created > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') - INTERVAL 1 DAY);"""
myCursor = connections[system_db].cursor()
results = myCursor.execute(query)    # Dies on this statement
resultcount = results.fetchall()
```

Why does this query work when I run it directly, but it fails when executed by my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There *is* a difference between your two queries:

First:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %k:%i:%s')
```

Django code:

```
STR_TO_DATE('2012-09-09 00:00:00-05:00','%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')
```

One has a `%k`, the other a `%H`. Perhaps that's the root of your problem?

Comment: The difference between %H and %k is the leading zero in the 24 hour clock. It should be %H and I've corrected the query. I can't believe I missed that. I've been staring at these two for a while looking for differences. Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't seem to have been the problem. I've modified the question slightly to indicate the queries do match now. Could the offset be the problem? It still runs if I run the query outside of python. Only after the query is added to the code does it have issues.

Comment: It's a little unfair to shift the question around like that; I'm afraid I don't know the answer to your new problem. Note that you may have gotten more attention from others had you created a new question for your new conundrum; also your title doesn't reflect your new problem.